# Read result of collectl command

Tags: linux, performance, monitoring

What does "inter" mean in the `collectl` command result ?

The output of this command is:

```
#<--------CPU--------><----------Disks-----------><----------Network---------->
#cpu sys inter  ctxsw KBRead  Reads KBWrit Writes   KBIn  PktIn  KBOut  PktOut 
   5   1  1880   5178      0      0      0      0      4     13     15      31
```

Answer (score 0):

interrupts

which can also be seen from /proc/interrupts